# How to change style of a table in a chrome extension?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i am currently developing an chrome extension for my university which serves as an enhancement suite for students and fixes the crappy css on our university login. i have changed most of the page but i am currently having problem targeting and changing the css of the table. here is the table code i want to target:

```
<form name="stud_login" action="stud_login_submit.asp" method="post">

        <input type="hidden" name="message" value="">

        <table cellpadding=2 cellspacing=0 border=2 bordercolor=#CC9900 width="434">
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor=#E1ECF2 align=center width="424" height="100">

                <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='4' align='center' border='1' width='428' height='100' style='border-collapse: collapse;' bordercolor='#FFFFFF'>

                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor=#5A768D colspan=2 height=30 align="center">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor=#5A768D width="117" height="33">
                        <font color=#FFFFFF><b>Register No.</b></font>
                    </td>
                    <td height="33" width="292">
                        <input type="text" name="regno" class="textbox2" size="20" maxlength="9" value="" tabindex="1">
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor=#5A768D width="117" height="36">
                        <font color=#FFFFFF><b>Password</b></font>
                    </td>
                    <td height="36" width="292">
                        <input type="password" name="passwd" class="textbox" size="20" maxlength="15" tabindex="1">
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor=#5A768D height="36" width="117" rowspan=2 valign=top>
                        <font color=#FFFFFF><b>Verification Code</b></font>
                    </td>
                    <td height="36" width="292" align=center bgcolor="#FFFFE8">
                        <img src="captcha.asp" id="imgCaptcha" onContextMenu="return false;" ondrag="return false;" onmousedown="return false;">
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td height="36" width="292">
                        <input type="text" name="vrfcd" class="textbox" size="10" maxlength="6" tabindex="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="RefreshImage('imgCaptcha');"><font color=blue>Change Verification Code</font></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan=2 bgcolor=#5A768D height=40 align=center>

                        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="submit3" onclick="return checknull()" tabindex="1">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <input type="button" value="Reset" class="submit3" onclick="call_reset()" tabindex="1">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <!--<input type="button" value="Forgot Password ?" class="submit3" onclick="modalWin(); return false;" tabindex="1">-->
                        <input type="button" value="Forgot Password ?" class="submit3" onclick="fgtpswd_popup(); return false;" tabindex="1">

                    </td>
                </tr>

                </table>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        </form>
```

I have changed it's button and hide it's not relevant details but i want to changes it's whole design through css and give it a modern design can anyone please give examples on how can i change it and make it look better.

Comment: You'll need to use a content script.  If your changes are just css, you can just have your extension provide a style sheet that overrides your school's.  Otherwise, you'll need to use some javascript to change things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify or even overwrite the contents of an existing web page you must use a **content script** or **inject Javascript code directly** into the page. *Make sure your Chrome Extension has the correct permissions for the url you are trying to interact with.*

More specifically, in order to inject a CSS file into the page, you can:

1) **Programmatically create a "style" node** in Javascript, edit its innerHTML and then pop this into the page

2) **Insert a stylesheet link** pointing to a file in your extension's directory. Please note that for this method you will need to list the stylesheet in your manifest.json's "web_accessible_resources" field.

Comment: You can also create a content script that injects css, not js.

Answer (score -1):

Please Use below Code :

```
 @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
    {
        //Your Css Here
    }
```

Comment: This media query enable only when your site will open in chrome browser

Comment: why do i need to use that